# Convert spring data page to list

Tags: java, spring-data

I have a page of object:

```
Page<Audit> audits = auditRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 10));
```

And I want to convert audits to list of object. `audit.getContent()` return just the single page's data. How to get everything from all pages?

Comment: just use List<Audit> audits = repo.findAll(); Is there a reason to retrieve by pagination in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (whole) point of pagination is to return partial data and page through it so you don't need to:

- Load everything into memory
- Worry about scrolling, total number of records, sorting and number of pages

However, if you want to get everything in one go then, you can call the overloaded version of `findAll` method (of `JPARepository`) which accepts no arguments (Javadoc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--)). Your code would look like this:

```
List<Audit> audits = auditRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: In my project, I want to find data by a keyword from all filed of database and page results. But I cannot use native query and PageRequest the same time. So I want to convert page to list, and find by keyword in the list.

Comment: @gavinSong That is a completely different question from the one you asked. Upvote and accept this answer because it answers the question you asked. Ask a new question.